# How do I pass data using sessions in Ruby CGI?

Tags: ruby, session

I am working on a guess-a-number game with Ruby that will be online. I know I need to pass the SESSION somehow to keep the number that they are guessing, but I have tried a ton of methods with no luck.  My code is [here](http://pastie.org/461976).

Any thoughts on what I can do get this code working? I have declared each of my sections.

Answer (score 1):

A session is, usually, a combination of a cookie [(session cookie)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_cookie), or some session id tacked onto the url, which has some unique identification of the current "session" and a way to save the data on the server and retrieve it when given the id from the cookie.

So I would set a cookie based on for example `ip + Time.now.to_i` and then save that ID and the values I want set into a database or a text file on the hard drive. Note that there is probably a lot better ways to create a unique ID but aim for the simple stuff first. :)

I also recommend that you look into `CGI::Session` which you require with `require 'cgi/session'`.